# How to have different matchers for server side and client side for request url in groovy based spring cloud contract

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

so I understand that this is not valid

```
Contract dsl =
        Contract.make {
            description "should return correct expected response"
            request {
                method GET()
                url value(consumer(regex('/v2/abc/user/[0-9]{9,18}')),producer(regex("/abc/v2/user/[0-9]{9,18}")))

                }

            }
            response {
                body([
                        id : $(consumer(regex('.*'))),

                ])
                status 200
            }
        }
```

The API gateway between the two sides producer and consumer transforms producer url to consumer. Does the spring cloud contract allow for such cases where API gateway changes the URL to look what is expected by the consumer?

When I try to do this the error is pretty clear

```
You can't have a regular expression for the request on the server side
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to have a regex on the producer side. That's because in the tests we need to send a concrete request to a concrete url. We can't find the url unless you tell us how it looks like.

Comment: Thanks..regex only on the consumer side solved my problem
 url $(consumer(~/(((?=.*(v2\/abc\/user)).*)|((?=.*(abc\/v2\/user)).*))\/[0-9]{9,18}/),producer('/abc/v2/user'))